# Lying about api version

Tags: nexus-5, android-versions, compatibility

I have this banking app that launches normally but then displays a message saying my android version is not supported. So I think there is just some simple if checking my android version. I'm using l preview.

Is there a way to lie about api version only for this app as it seems to launch otherwise ok.

Comment: It *might* be possible to do it with Xposed Framework, but it's not a good idea. Often version checks can also enable or disable behaviour or features for specific versions, so making the app think the version is different might cause unexpected behaviour or crashes.

Comment: But it did work on 4.4.4 with art enabled so I would think it would be pretty safe.

Comment: You're missing the point. It might work when it knows it's running on a given version, but not if it thinks it's running on a different version.

Comment: Well no harm trying. If somebody knows a good way please answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for 2 hours. I didn't find any Xposed modules, nor any apps that will do this on per-app basis. But you can change the response for your Android version. This is accomplished by changing the version in your build.prop file. This will be a PIA. It also involves some type of risk, so this will be on you if anything goes wrong. Read the last part of my answer more than once.

This involves root, build.prop file, backup build.prop, modified build.prop. Switching files around with a file browser. Rebooting. Using your app. Switching files around. Rebooting.

**OR**

Download one of the many ***`build.prop editors`*** available on the Play Store. Find an open source one. You can edit the version inside the editor app. It will have options for backup of build.prop file as well. Rebooting still required.

---

***`ALWAYS MAKE A BACKUP/NANDROID WHEN MAKING CHANGES TO THE SYSTEM`***